# ¿Cómo acceder a relación 1:m en Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

estoy haciendo una API en Ruby on Rails, soy nuevo en este lenguaje y tengo problemas para acceder a las relaciones que tengo, tengo 'comidas' que se relacionan con una categoría, lo que busco hacer es que la API regrese toda la comida que esta registrada con sus respectivas categorías, quiero que se mande como se muestra continuación:

**Salida**

```
{
    "status": "Success",

    "message": "All foods DESC",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Una",
            "size": 12,
            "portion": "Vasos",
            "category": "Frutas",
            "updated_at": "2018-09-28T18:50:01.137Z"
        },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Otra",
        "size": 4,
        "portion": "cucharadas",
        "category": "Frutas",
        "updated_at": "2018-09-28T18:50:01.137Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Otraxs",
        "size": 4,
        "portion": "cucharadas",
        "category": "Leguminosas",
        "updated_at": "2018-09-28T18:50:01.137Z"
    }
    ]
}
```

**Modelos**

**Categoria**

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    # Asociación con modelos.
    has_many :foods, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**Comida**

```
class Food < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :category
end
```

**Controlador**

```
def index
    food = Food.order('created_at DESC')
    foods = []
    food.each { |f| foods << 
        {  :id => f.id, 
            :name => f.name, 
            :size => f.size,
            :portion => f.portion,
            :category => f.category.name,
            :updated_at => f.updated_at
        } 
    }
    render json: {status: 'Success', message: 'All foods DESC', data: foods}, status: :ok
end
```

Así como se muestra la salida, es la forma en que lo quiero, donde me muestre cual es el nombre de la categoría a la que pertenece, esto ya lo logré como se muestra en el controlador, sin embargo pienso que no es la forma correcta y quiero algo de asesoramiento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la gema Active Record Serializers https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

Para que de esa manera puedas crear un serializer para tu modelo y al ser enviado como json automaticamente tenga la estructura que tu definas.

En este ejemplo se incluyen los atributos de Food que quieres para tu json y además incluye un JSON Object con los atributos de la categoría a la que pertenece:

```
class FoodSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :size, :portion, :updated_at
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Quedando así:

```
{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Una",
        "size": 12,
        "portion": "Vasos",
        "category": {
          # Atributos de Category
        },
        "updated_at": "2018-09-28T18:50:01.137Z"
    }
```

O puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera para que en lugar de incluir un JSON Object para category, agregue solo el campo que tu quieres:

```
class FoodSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :size, :portion, :updated_at, :category

  def category
    object.category.name
  end

end
```

Queda así:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Una",
  "size": 12,
  "portion": "Vasos",
  "category": "Frutas",
  "updated_at": "2018-09-28T18:50:01.137Z"
}
```

**EDIT:**

Tu acción en el controlador quedaría de esta forma

```
def index
    foods = Food.order('created_at DESC')
    foods_json = ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(foods, adapter: :json).as_json
    render json: {status: 'Success', message: 'All foods DESC', data: foods_json}, status: :ok
end
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, esto me ayudo bastante y fue la solución.

Comment: Solo una duda, sabes, ¿cómo podría mantener mi render actual? `render json: {status: 'Success', message: 'All foods DESC', data: foods}, status: :ok` por que solo me funcionó si lo hacía así `render json: foods`

Comment: Si, he editado mi respuesta para que lo que quieres sea posible.